# Hold dual citizenship for/of

Tags: prepositions

I came across this sentence in one of the facebook posts.

"I hold dual citizenship for New Zealand and Australia"

Is it okay if I replace "for" with " of"?

"I hold dual citizenship of New Zealand and Australia"

Thank you

Comment: The person who wrote the sentence seems like a native speaker, so I kinda gave her the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely say "I hold dual citizenship **of** New Zealand and Australia".

I've never come across "for" in this context.

"Of" is the usual preposition used to specify country names after "citizen", "citizenship", "national" and "nationality" (NGrams [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=citizenship%20for%20the%20United%2Ccitizenship%20of%20the%20United%2Cdual%20citizen%20of%20the%20United%2Cdual%20citizen%20for%20the%20United%2Ccitizen%20of%20the%20United%2Ccitizen%20for%20the%20United&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccitizenship%20for%20the%20United%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccitizenship%20of%20the%20United%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdual%20citizen%20of%20the%20United%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccitizen%20of%20the%20United%3B%2Cc0) virtually no "for"s).  "For" would be used when specifying a length of time ("I have held dual citizenship for the last three years") or a purpose or cause ("I hold dual citizenship for family reasons").